# Apache2 reverse proxy https <-> http with digest authentication

Tags: proxy, https, http, apache2

Sorry, If I posted a repeated question. Didn't find my answer yet.

What I have is:

- a webservice on LAN which is only accesable over HTTP ans uses Digest Auth
- another server in LAN which has Apache2 service, that I would like to use as HTTP/HTTPS proxy

I enabled listen to 8888 port and added this config:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName local_domain
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /cam http://local_ip
    ProxyPassReverse /cam http://local_ip
</VirtualHost>
```

Proxy works, but the authentication doesn't go through. On visit a login popup show. If I enter wrong credentials, the response is ok, 401 Authorization required. But if I enter correct credentials I receive error 400 Bad Request.

What's the issue? I guess something is either missin or incorrect in HTTP header? Should somehow the cookie be forwarded?

Can you give me a hint? :)

thanks!
Mario